# Webpack "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/'"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have two HTML pages, each will include it's own bundle. Here is my project structure:

```
public/
-- dist/
src/
-- firebase/
-- network/
webpack.config.js
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanTerminalPlugin = require('clean-terminal-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        network: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/network/index.ts',
        firebase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/firebase/index.ts'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public') + '/dist',
    },
    plugins: [new CleanTerminalPlugin()]
};
```

I expect this to create two bundles in `public/dist` with the names `firebase.js` and `network.js`. Instead I get an error:

`ERROR in main Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/' in 'path/to/project/root'`

It also says `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /path/to/project/root/src/index doesn't exist`
And repeats that for `.tsx`, `.ts` and `.js`

I don't know why it's looking for an `index.*` file in my `src/`. I didn't specify that as an entry file. If I create a `src/index.ts` it builds, but only makes one bundle called `main` which is not my expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a really stupid issue, but I'll post the answer in case someone needs it.

I was invoking webpack with `webpack ./src` but `webpack` without the `./src` worked as expected.